# Formatting with SQL DATEPART

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am using `DATEPART(WEEK,mydate)` to return the week number of my date, but when the week is only single number i.e. at the beginning of the year I want to format it as `01` instead of `1`.

I am using SQL Server 2014, I have tried using the option `format(datepart(week,mydate),'ww')` but am just getting `ww` as my answer which as you can tell isn't quite right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) with `d2`

```
SELECT FORMAT(datepart(week,'2017-01-05'), 'd2')
-- RETURN 01

SELECT FORMAT(datepart(week,GETDATE()), 'd2')
-- RETURN 23
```

Comment: That's brilliant Arulkumar, exactly what I wanted and I've learnt something new this morning.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 SELECT RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE())), 2)
--selects 23
 SELECT RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(WEEK,'2017-01-01 03:58:13.110')), 2)
-- selects 01
```